# Testar se todas as funções assíncronas foram encerradas

Tags: javascript, node.js, async, assincronismo, electron

Saudações
Estou desenvolvendo um sincronizador entre dois bancos de dados (`SQL Server` e `MySQL`) com o `ElectronJS` e o `Node.JS` e está tudo funcionando certinho, mas eu gostaria que ao realizar a sincronização de todas as tabelas (que são feitas de forma assíncrona dentro de um loop `for`) ele executasse o método `window.close()` para encerrar a aplicação.

```js
// Removi os tratamentos de erro e conexão com o banco, porque estão funcionando

// Leio um arquivo .json que possui todas as tabelas com as colunas que eu desejo
fs.readFile(ABSPATH + 'tables.json', 'utf8', async (err,json) => {
  // Converte o conteúdo do arquivo pra um objeto JSON
  let vetor = JSON.parse(json)
  // Para cada tabela
  for (let i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    // Lê a tabela no SQL Server e salva os dados no MySQL
    await read(vetor[i].table,vetor[i].keys)
  }
  // Ao invés de fechar, estou só exibindo na tela essa mensagem (pra debug)
  document.body.innerHTML += "<h2>Todos os dados foram inseridos</h2>"
})
```

Mas, como podem ver, ele está retornando o resultado final antes de retornar as funções, ou seja, elas permanecem assíncronas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que meu erro esteja no momento de salvar os dados, na seguinte função, porque testei ela com o `console.log()`, mas mesmo assim, não consigo torná-la síncrona:

```js
con.connect(async err => {
  // Começo a Transaction
  await con.beginTransaction(async err => {
    // Limpo a tabela
    await con.query(`TRUNCATE TABLE ${table}`, err => {})
    // Loop pra inserir todos os dados na tabela
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
      // Crio e executo um insert
      await con.query(createInsert(table,keys,values[0]), err => {})
    }
    // Encerro a Transaction quando está tudo inserido
    await con.commit(err => {
        // Escrevo na tela que os dados foram salvos
        document.body.innerHTML += `<p>Dados de ${table} cadastrados com sucesso.</p>`
    })
  })
  // Fim da Transaction
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nary, o operador `await` faz o seu código esperar pela resolução de uma `Promise`, ele não torna seu código síncrono. Para utilizar `await`, essas funções precisam retornar uma `promise`, o que não sei se é o caso do seu código, e além disso, não faz sentido utilizar `callbacks`, quando você já está utilizando `await`.

Se o seu objeto não retorna promises, você pode criar novos métodos. Existem outras abordagens para esse problema, mas essa é uma sugestão:

```js
Object.defineProperty(con.__proto__, {
  asyncConnect: {
    configurable: true,
    value() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.connect(err => err ? reject(err) : resolve()))
    }
  },

  asyncBeginTransaction: {
    configurable: true,
    value() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.beginTransaction(err => err ? reject(err) : resolve()))
    }
  },

  asyncQuery: {
    configurable: true,
    value(arg) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.query(arg, err => err ? reject(err) : resolve()))
    }
  },

  asyncCommit: {
    configurable: true,
    value() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.commit(err => err ? reject(err) : resolve()))
    }
  }
});
```

Agora com esses métodos você pode utilizar o operador `await`. Note que eu não utilizo mais `callbacks`.

```js
await con.asyncConnect()
// Começo a Transaction
await con.asyncBeginTransaction()
// Limpo a tabela
await con.asyncQuery(`TRUNCATE TABLE ${table}`)
// Loop pra inserir todos os dados na tabela
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // Crio e executo um insert
  await con.asyncQuery(createInsert(table, keys, values[i]))
}
// Encerro a Transaction quando está tudo inserido
await con.asyncCommit()
// Escrevo na tela que os dados foram salvos
document.body.innerHTML += `<p>Dados de ${table} cadastrados com sucesso.</p>`
```

É claro, esse código é apenas uma versão adaptada do que você postou. Ainda é necessário fazer algumas melhorias como tratamento de erro e mover essa lógica para o back end.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou como esperado (pelo menos esse problema).